# Alternate way of Exists with Having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

The below query is to retrieve the records whose (SGT_DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST) count is only one. It is working great. But performance wise it didn't took so much of time since we have 100 000 records.

Is there any better way to do it?

```
   SELECT PA.PERSON_ID,
   PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID,
   DR.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID,
   SUM
   (  
        ISNULL(CD.EE_PRE_TAX_AMT,0) + 
        ISNULL(CD.EE_ADDL_PRE_TAX_AMT,0)
   ) AS EE_PRE_TAX_CONTRIB,
   DD.PRE_TAX_AMOUNT AS DISB_DTL_PRE_TAX_AMOUNT,
   SUM
   (     ISNULL(CD.EE_POST_TAX_AMT,0) + 
         ISNULL(CD.EE_ADDL_POST_TAX_AMT,0)
   ) AS EE_POST_TAX_CONTRIB,
   DD.POST_TAX_AMOUNT AS DISB_DTL_POST_TAX_AMOUNT
   FROM SGT_DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST DR
   INNER JOIN SGT_DISBURSEMENT_DETAIL DD ON DR.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID = DD.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID 
   INNER JOIN SGT_PERSON_ACCOUNT PA ON PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID = DR.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID
   INNER JOIN SGT_CONTRIB_DTL CD ON CD.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID = PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID 
   WHERE DR.REQUEST_CATEGORY_VALUE = 'REFD' AND
         DD.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE = 'REFD' AND
         CD.STATUS_VALUE = 'VALD' AND
         CD.POSTED_DATE <= DR.ACCEPTED_TO_PAYROLL_DATE AND
         DR.DISBURSEMENT_STATUS_VALUE <> 'CANL' AND
      EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM SGT_DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST SDR1 
            INNER JOIN SGT_DISBURSEMENT_DETAIL SDD1 ON SDD1.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID = SDR1.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID
            WHERE SDR1.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID = DR.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID and SDD1.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE = DD.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE
            GROUP BY SDR1.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID 
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
   GROUP BY 
        PA.PERSON_ID, PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID, DR.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID, DD.PRE_TAX_AMOUNT, DD.POST_TAX_AMOUNT
```

Answer (score 0):

For Performance improvement you can have the Filter Conditions in the Join Clause, instead of where clause. In this case each join will restrict the results to even lesser number of rows.

```
        SELECT PA.PERSON_ID,
           PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID,
           DR.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID,
           SUM
           (  
                ISNULL(CD.EE_PRE_TAX_AMT,0) + 
                ISNULL(CD.EE_ADDL_PRE_TAX_AMT,0)
           ) AS EE_PRE_TAX_CONTRIB,
           DD.PRE_TAX_AMOUNT AS DISB_DTL_PRE_TAX_AMOUNT,
           SUM
           (     ISNULL(CD.EE_POST_TAX_AMT,0) + 
                 ISNULL(CD.EE_ADDL_POST_TAX_AMT,0)
           ) AS EE_POST_TAX_CONTRIB,
           DD.POST_TAX_AMOUNT AS DISB_DTL_POST_TAX_AMOUNT
           FROM SGT_DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST DR
           INNER JOIN SGT_DISBURSEMENT_DETAIL DD ON     DR.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID = DD.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID AND DR.REQUEST_CATEGORY_VALUE = 'REFD' AND
                 DD.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE = 'REFD' AND DR.DISBURSEMENT_STATUS_VALUE <> 'CANL'
           INNER JOIN SGT_PERSON_ACCOUNT PA ON PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID = DR.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID
           INNER JOIN SGT_CONTRIB_DTL CD ON CD.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID = PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID AND CD.STATUS_VALUE = 'VALD' AND
                 CD.POSTED_DATE <= DR.ACCEPTED_TO_PAYROLL_DATE
           WHERE EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT 1 FROM SGT_DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST SDR1 
                    INNER JOIN SGT_DISBURSEMENT_DETAIL SDD1 ON SDD1.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID = SDR1.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID
                    WHERE SDR1.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID = DR.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID and SDD1.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE = DD.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE
                    GROUP BY SDR1.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID 
                    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                )
           GROUP BY 
                PA.PERSON_ID, PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID, DR.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID, DD.PRE_TAX_AMOUNT, DD.POST_TAX_AMOUNT
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use count over it should give you the same result and be better for performance:

```
select * from (
SELECT PA.PERSON_ID,
   PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID,
   DR.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID,
   SUM
   (  
        ISNULL(CD.EE_PRE_TAX_AMT,0) + 
        ISNULL(CD.EE_ADDL_PRE_TAX_AMT,0)
   ) AS EE_PRE_TAX_CONTRIB,
   DD.PRE_TAX_AMOUNT AS DISB_DTL_PRE_TAX_AMOUNT,
   SUM
   (     ISNULL(CD.EE_POST_TAX_AMT,0) + 
         ISNULL(CD.EE_ADDL_POST_TAX_AMT,0)
   ) AS EE_POST_TAX_CONTRIB,
   DD.POST_TAX_AMOUNT AS DISB_DTL_POST_TAX_AMOUNT
   ,count(*) over(partition by PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID ) as  ct
   FROM SGT_DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST DR
   INNER JOIN SGT_DISBURSEMENT_DETAIL DD ON DR.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID = DD.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID 
   INNER JOIN SGT_PERSON_ACCOUNT PA ON PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID = DR.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID
   INNER JOIN SGT_CONTRIB_DTL CD ON CD.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID = PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID 
   WHERE DR.REQUEST_CATEGORY_VALUE = 'REFD' AND
         DD.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE = 'REFD' AND
         CD.STATUS_VALUE = 'VALD' AND
         CD.POSTED_DATE <= DR.ACCEPTED_TO_PAYROLL_DATE AND
         DR.DISBURSEMENT_STATUS_VALUE <> 'CANL' 

   GROUP BY 
        PA.PERSON_ID, PA.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID, DR.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID, DD.PRE_TAX_AMOUNT, DD.PRE_TAX_AMOUNT, DD.POST_TAX_AMOUNT
        ) as x 
where x.ct = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would materialize this to a #temp

```
SELECT DR1.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID, SDD1.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE
  FROM SGT_DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST SDR1 
  JOIN SGT_DISBURSEMENT_DETAIL SDD1 
         ON SDD1.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID = SDR1.DISBURSEMENT_REQUEST_ID
 GROUP BY SDR1.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID, SDD1.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

join #temp 
      on #temp.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID = DR.PERSON_ACCOUNT_ID
     and #temp.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE = DD.DETAIL_CATEGORY_VALUE
```